# phpmailer - ajax send email with parameters not working

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

I'm trying to send email with Phpmailer library. It's really basic but couldn't manage to handle.

Here is my javascript code.

```
function sendemail() {
    var $adtext = $("#ad").val();
         var $gonderentext = $("#mail").val();
         var $mesajtext = $("#mesaj").val();
  $.ajax({

       url: '/mail.php',
      type: 'post',
       data:{action:'call_this', ad: $adtext, gonderen: $gonderentext, mesaj: $mesajtext},
       success:function(html) {
        alert("İletişim mailiniz gönderildi.");
       }


  });
```

}

And here is my Php file (mail.php)

```
<?php
 include( "class.phpmailer.php" );
 include( "class.pop3.php" );
 include( "class.smtp.php" );
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
SendMailWithGmailSMTP("deneme@senlikorg.com","İletişim Mail",$_POST['mesaj'],$_POST['mail']);


};




function SendMailWithGmailSMTP($to,$subject,$text,$maill)
{
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->Host="ssl://pro06.ni.net.tr:465";
$mail->Username="deneme@senlikorg.com";
$mail->Password="xxx";
$mail->From=$maill;
$mail->FromName=$text;
$mail->CharSet="iso-8859-9";
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Subject=$subject;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body=$text;
if($mail->Send()) return true;
else echo $mail->ErrorInfo;

}




?>
```

Could you please help me to figure out what's wrong? Thanks in advance. Have a wonderful night.

Comment: what error are you getting `$mail->ErrorInfo;` here?

Comment: Base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer; it looks like you've used some very old code from somewhere else. PHPMailer isn't slow, but SMTP can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, problem is you are using wrong param as `$_POST['mail']` rather than `$_POST['gonderen']` that you are sending in your `ajax` post data

Try changing your php line like this:

```
SendMailWithGmailSMTP("deneme@senlikorg.com","İletişim Mail",$_POST['mesaj'],$_POST['gonderen']);
```

Also, let me know if you are getting any error on this line `$mail->ErrorInfo;` here !

Comment: Tried, still nothing tho. And i don't get any errorInfo back. maybe phpmailer is kinda slow?

Comment: Try `echo "if"; exit` and `echo 'else'; exit;` inside `if` and `else` conditions and let me know in which your code is going? Also if code is executing `if` then do check your email `spam` as well

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad at all. Contacted with my host provider and found out i was using wrong port. Thanks everyone.